# How to edit or update a value from Firebase database - android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure:

```
"Posts":
      key:
        numberx: 1
        numbery: 2
```

I want to edit or update the value of the numberx

I try this but doesn't works

```
 getPostRef.child("Posts").child("key").child("numberx").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                        long num = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
                                        mutableData.setValue(num + 1);


                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);

                                    }
```

Comment: What is the `error`?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this please use this code:

```
@Override
public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData mutableData) {
    if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
        mutableData.setValue("0");
    } else {
        String numberXString = (String) mutableData.getValue();
        int numberx = Integer.parseInt(numberXString);
        int increasedNumberX = numberx + 1;
        mutableData.setValue(String.valueOf(increasedNumberX));
    }
    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle cases when there is no value. I think you need something like this

```
public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
long value = 0;
if(mutableData.getValue() != null) {
    String num = (String) mutableData.getValue();
    value = Long.parseLong(num);
}
value++;
mutableData.setValue(value);
return Transaction.success(mutableData);
}
```